# JPA lazy loading of @ElementCollection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

After reading several web pages I still do't understand why my @ElementCollection are loaded eagerly. My understanding is that any @ElementCollection shall always be loaded lazily by default. As you see, that is not the case - you'll see the console output at the end of this post. I tried to enforce lazy loading with *@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)* annotation, but that doesn't change anything. Can someone explain and also state how to change the annotation in order to load lazily?

I have a JavaFX application. Hence, I must use Properties and AccessType.PROPERTY. Changing this is not an option. Further, I am using: Java 11, Hibernate 5.4.15.Final, MySQL 8, Spring boot 2.2.7

This is an excerpt from the entity class

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(Term.PRODUCT)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)    
public class Product extends Term {
    ...
    protected ListProperty<Double> marketSize;
    protected ListProperty<Double> marketGrowth;
    protected ListProperty<Integer> marketUnits;
    ...
    public Product() {
        ...
        marketSize = new SimpleListProperty<>();
        marketGrowth = new SimpleListProperty<>();
        marketUnits = new SimpleListProperty<>();
        ...
    }

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Double> getMarketSize() {
        return marketSize;
    }


    public void setMarketSize(List<Double> marketSize) {
        this.marketSize = new SimpleListProperty<Double>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(marketSize));
    }

    public ListProperty<Double> marketSizeProperty() {
        return marketSize;
    }

    // Likewise for marketGrowth and marketUnits

    ...
}
```

related Service class

```
@Service
public class TermService {

    ...

    public ObservableList<Product> getAllProducts() {
        ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        products.addAll(productRepository.findAll());
    
        return products;
    }
}
```

related Repository classes

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends TermRepository<Product> {

}
```

and

```
 @NoRepositoryBean`
        public interface TermRepository<T extends Term> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
        
            List<T> findByIdentifier(String indentifier);
            List<T> findByGoal(String goal);
            List<Product> findByParent(Term parent);
            List<T> findAll();
            T getById(Long id);
        }
```

When my business logic calls the getAllProducts() from the TermService it results in the following (extract)

```
DEBUG 09:01 o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement:128: select term0_.id as id2_66_1_, term0_.goal as goal3_66_1_, term0_.identifier as identifi4_66_1_, term0_.level as level5_66_1_, term0_.parent_id as parent_46_66_1_, term0_.plannedBegin as plannedb6_66_1_, term0_.plannedEnd as plannede7_66_1_, term0_.state as state8_66_1_, term0_.fk_successor as fk_succ47_66_1_, term0_.fk_testplan as fk_test48_66_1_, term0_.timeUnit as timeunit9_66_1_, term0_.type as type10_66_1_, term0_.version as version11_66_1_, term0_.affection as affecti12_66_1_, term0_.classification as classif13_66_1_, term0_.classificationJustification as classif14_66_1_, term0_.customerCharacteristics as custome15_66_1_, term0_.customerDenomination as custome16_66_1_, term0_.devMaterialCosts as devmate17_66_1_, term0_.directive as directi18_66_1_, term0_.factoryCosts as factory19_66_1_, term0_.fixedCosts as fixedco20_66_1_, term0_.generalAdminCosts as general21_66_1_, term0_.iec60601 as iec22_66_1_, term0_.iec62304 as iec23_66_1_, term0_.iec62366 as iec24_66_1_, term0_.intendedUse as intende25_66_1_, term0_.iso13485 as iso26_66_1_, term0_.iso14155 as iso27_66_1_, term0_.iso14971 as iso28_66_1_, term0_.leasingCosts as leasing29_66_1_, term0_.manufacturingCosts as manufac30_66_1_, term0_.marketGeography as marketg31_66_1_, term0_.marketValueSegment as marketv32_66_1_, term0_.negativeImpact as negativ33_66_1_, term0_.prodMaterialCosts as prodmat34_66_1_, term0_.productLine_id as product49_66_1_, term0_.fk_prodowner as fk_prod50_66_1_, term0_.fk_prjmanager as fk_prjm51_66_1_, term0_.projectedSalesPrice as project35_66_1_, term0_.purpose as purpose36_66_1_, term0_.reach as reach37_66_1_, term0_.fk_regmanager as fk_regm52_66_1_, term0_.restriction as restric38_66_1_, term0_.rohs as rohs39_66_1_, term0_.salaryCosts as salaryc40_66_1_, term0_.salesAdminCosts as salesad41_66_1_, term0_.systemDescription as systemd42_66_1_, term0_.fk_sysengineer as fk_syse53_66_1_, term0_.technologyReadinessLevel as technol43_66_1_, term0_.unlike as unlike44_66_1_, term0_.varCosts as varcost45_66_1_, term0_.term_level as term_lev1_66_1_, term1_.id as id2_66_0_, term1_.goal as goal3_66_0_, term1_.identifier as identifi4_66_0_, term1_.level as level5_66_0_, term1_.parent_id as parent_46_66_0_, term1_.plannedBegin as plannedb6_66_0_, term1_.plannedEnd as plannede7_66_0_, term1_.state as state8_66_0_, term1_.fk_successor as fk_succ47_66_0_, term1_.fk_testplan as fk_test48_66_0_, term1_.timeUnit as timeunit9_66_0_, term1_.type as type10_66_0_, term1_.version as version11_66_0_, term1_.affection as affecti12_66_0_, term1_.classification as classif13_66_0_, term1_.classificationJustification as classif14_66_0_, term1_.customerCharacteristics as custome15_66_0_, term1_.customerDenomination as custome16_66_0_, term1_.devMaterialCosts as devmate17_66_0_, term1_.directive as directi18_66_0_, term1_.factoryCosts as factory19_66_0_, term1_.fixedCosts as fixedco20_66_0_, term1_.generalAdminCosts as general21_66_0_, term1_.iec60601 as iec22_66_0_, term1_.iec62304 as iec23_66_0_, term1_.iec62366 as iec24_66_0_, term1_.intendedUse as intende25_66_0_, term1_.iso13485 as iso26_66_0_, term1_.iso14155 as iso27_66_0_, term1_.iso14971 as iso28_66_0_, term1_.leasingCosts as leasing29_66_0_, term1_.manufacturingCosts as manufac30_66_0_, term1_.marketGeography as marketg31_66_0_, term1_.marketValueSegment as marketv32_66_0_, term1_.negativeImpact as negativ33_66_0_, term1_.prodMaterialCosts as prodmat34_66_0_, term1_.productLine_id as product49_66_0_, term1_.fk_prodowner as fk_prod50_66_0_, term1_.fk_prjmanager as fk_prjm51_66_0_, term1_.projectedSalesPrice as project35_66_0_, term1_.purpose as purpose36_66_0_, term1_.reach as reach37_66_0_, term1_.fk_regmanager as fk_regm52_66_0_, term1_.restriction as restric38_66_0_, term1_.rohs as rohs39_66_0_, term1_.salaryCosts as salaryc40_66_0_, term1_.salesAdminCosts as salesad41_66_0_, term1_.systemDescription as systemd42_66_0_, term1_.fk_sysengineer as fk_syse53_66_0_, term1_.technologyReadinessLevel as technol43_66_0_, term1_.unlike as unlike44_66_0_, term1_.varCosts as varcost45_66_0_, term1_.term_level as term_lev1_66_0_ from Term term0_ left outer join Term term1_ on term0_.id=term1_.fk_successor where term0_.fk_successor=? 
DEBUG 09:01 o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement:128: select marketgrow0_.Product_id as product_1_29_0_, marketgrow0_.marketGrowth as marketgr2_29_0_ from Product_marketGrowth marketgrow0_ where marketgrow0_.Product_id=? 
DEBUG 09:01 o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement:128: select marketsize0_.Product_id as product_1_31_0_, marketsize0_.marketSize as marketsi2_31_0_ from Product_marketSize marketsize0_ where marketsize0_.Product_id=? 
DEBUG 09:01 o.h.e.j.s.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement:128: select marketunit0_.Product_id as product_1_33_0_, marketunit0_.marketUnits as marketun2_33_0_ from Product_marketUnits marketunit0_ where marketunit0_.Product_id=?
```

I would expect only the first line, but not the last three lines.

Comment: Did you try to reproduce your problem on pure hibernate application without inheritance in the entities hierarchy and with usage only collections from `java.util.*`?

Comment: No, not yet. I hope someone knows the issue or can at least explain the behavior. If that is not the case in a few days, I can start with a "clean" mock and increase the inheritance and collections complexity in order to try to reproduce.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the getter. I bet you access the value somehow which causes the lazy initialization.

Comment: You lost the bet. I tried it before I posted the question but forgot to mention. Anyway, I just tried again. The debugger doesn't stop in any of the three methods

Answer (score 0):

If an element collection is annotated(or xml mapping) as LAZY, it should not be loaded unless there is an EntityGraph hint. Try another JPA provider such as cmobilecom-jpa that generates optimized SQL.